# ASP.NET : Why can I read session cookies even if no cookie exists?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, session, cookies

It appears that I am able to read the `SessionID` at any time, even if no cookie currently exists!

```
Dim SessionID As String = Request.Cookies("ASP.NET_SessionId").Value
```

This code will always return a value, presumably the ID held by **IIS** server side.

The cookie appears to be generated only when a request to store session information is made.

**Why is this?**

and ...

If I am using session state server will the `SessionID` ever differ from the cookie `SessionID` and which take priority if one of the ID's is lost or reset?

**EDIT**

If the app_pool is reset. A new session ID must be created will this cause the session cookie to be updated also? As this could create potential conflicts for users already logged in.

Comment: When the session cookie is lost (deleted, expires), asp.net will generate another one to hold sessionId, so that at all times, you have a consistent way to refer to Session("something") and get the intended behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a user accesses a website powered by **ASP.NET** IIS generates a `SessionID` to uniquely idetinfy the users session.

If the website is using cookies:

```
<sessionState mode="StateServer" cookieless="UseCookies"/>
```

A cookie named `ASP.NET_SessionId` will be generated only when a request to store session information is made by the webpage. If no session information is stored a cookie will not be created but the user will still have an active `SessionID`.

The `SessionID` is read from **IIS** when no cookie is present.

The `SessionID` on the server always takes precedence and will update the session cookie when a new request to store information in the cookie is made.

Answer (score 0):

Every time that an user access the website and a session is opened ASP.Net by default creates a SessionID unless you specify the cookieless option:

If you are using a session state server the SessionID should be the same across all web servers otherwise you wouldn't be able to find the same user.

If the ID is lost or reset the state server will simply create a new one and write a new cookie with the new SessionID and the old one will be deleted after the expiration time.

Comment: This is not entirely true. You can test it yourself. A `SessionID` is generated when the user accesses the website but the `cookie is not` generated until a request to store session information is made. If no session information is stored a cookie will not be created but the user will still have an active sessionid.